# Does gaining Unnatural Strength from two sources cause them to combine?

Tags: attributes, dark-heresy-2e

Say if a character with Unnatural Strength (1) puts on power armour, again granting him Unnatural Strength (1). Is the second instance invalidated, or do they combine into Unnatural Strength (2)?

This is second edition Dark Heresy.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went ahead and submitted your question to Fantasy Flight Games for clarification, as my own research into this subject got me no definitive answer. Their reply should clear things up for you.

> *Hey guys, I have a question about the Unnatural Characteristic (X) trait in Dark Heresy 2nd Edition and whether the effects stack from multiple sources or not. A PC has the Unnatural Strength (1) trait and is getting Power Armour with also grants Unnatural Strength (1). Would he have US (2) when donning the armour or no? Thanks!*
>
> ---
>
> *Hi David! **Yes, those indeed stack.***
>
> *-Tim Huckelbery, RPG Producer, Fantasy Flight Games*